# I have used AutoCrat and it doesn't send email back with merged image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Have a great day. Your help will be valuable. I just have typed in all data for autoCrat with a form trigger.

[image]

However, after tested the form and waited for 30 minutes. Still didn't get the email with the image as an image above.

[image]

Then I tried another approach which was clicking through the AutoCrat window, but it appeared as the image above and didn't get the email with an image.

How to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Click File > Settings > Set your 'Time zone'. After done this, it worked well for me.